# How to reduce the time consumed by the for loop?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, image-processing, vectorization

I am trying to implement a simple pixel level center-surround image enhancement. Center-surround technique makes use of statistics between the center pixel of the window and the surrounding neighborhood as a means to decide what enhancement needs to be done. In the code given below I have compared the center pixel with average of the surrounding information and based on that I switch between two cases to enhance the contrast. The code that I have written is as follows:

```
im = normalize8(im,1);     %to set the range of pixel from 0-255
s1 = floor(K1/2);          %K1 is the size of the window for surround
M = 1000;                  %is a constant value
out1 = padarray(im,[s1,s1],'symmetric');
out1 = CE(out1,s1,M);
out = (out1(s1+1:end-s1,s1+1:end-s1));
out = normalize8(out,0);   %to set the range of pixel from 0-1



function [out] = CE(out,s,M)
  B = 255;
  out1 = out;
  for i = s+1 : size(out,1) - s
    for j = s+1 : size(out,2) - s
        temp = out(i-s:i+s,j-s:j+s);
        Yij = out1(i,j);
        Sij = (1/(2*s+1)^2)*sum(sum(temp));
          if (Yij>=Sij)
            Aij = A(Yij-Sij,M);
            out1(i,j) = ((B + Aij)*Yij)/(Aij+Yij);
          else
            Aij = A(Sij-Yij,M);
            out1(i,j) = (Aij*Yij)/(Aij+B-Yij);
          end
      end
   end
out = out1;
function [Ax] = A(x,M)
   if x == 0
       Ax = M;
   else 
       Ax = M/x;
    end
```

The code does the following things:
1) Normalize the image to 0-255 range and pad it with additional elements to perform windowing operation.
2) Calls the function CE.
3) In the function CE obtain the windowed image(temp).
4) Find the average of the window (Sij).
5) Compare the center of the window (Yij) with the average value (Sij).
6) Based on the result of comparison perform one of the two enhancement operation.
7) Finally set the range back to 0-1.

I have to run this for multiple window size (K1,K2,K3, etc.) and the images are of size 1728*2034. When the window size is selected as 100, the time consumed is very high.

Can I use vectorization at some stage to reduce the time for loops?

The profiler result (for window size 21) is as follows:
[image: Profiler timing 21*21 window]

The profiler result (for window size 100) is as follows:
[image: Profiler timing 100*100 window]

I have changed the code of my function and have written it without the sub-function. The code is as follows:

```
function [out] = CE(out,s,M)
B = 255;
Aij = zeros(1,2);
out1 = out;
n_factor = (1/(2*s+1)^2);
for i = s+1 : size(out,1) - s
    for j = s+1 : size(out,2) - s
        temp = out(i-s:i+s,j-s:j+s);
        Yij = out1(i,j);
        Sij = n_factor*sum(sum(temp));
        if Yij-Sij == 0
            Aij(1) = M;
            Aij(2) = M;
        else
            Aij(1) = M/(Yij-Sij);
            Aij(2) = M/(Sij-Yij);
        end
        if (Yij>=Sij)
            out1(i,j) = ((B + Aij(1))*Yij)/(Aij(1)+Yij);
        else
            out1(i,j) = (Aij(2)*Yij)/(Aij(2)+B-Yij);
        end
    end
end
out = out1;
```

There is a slight improvement in the speed from 93 sec to 88 sec. Suggestions for any other improvements to my code are welcomed.

I have tried to incorporate the suggestions given to replace sliding window with convolution and then vectorize the rest of it. The code below is my implementation and I'm not getting the result expected.

```
function [out_im] = CE_conv(im,s,M)
B = 255;
temp = ones(2*s,2*s);
temp = temp ./ numel(temp);
out1 = conv2(im,temp,'same');
out_im = im;
Aij = im-out1;                             %same as Yij-Sij
Aij1 = out1-im;                            %same as Sij-Yij
Mij = Aij;
Mij(Aij>0) = M./Aij(Aij>0);                % if Yij>Sij  Mij = M/Yij-Sij;
Mij(Aij<0) = M./Aij1(Aij<0);               % if Yij<Sij  Mij = M/Sij-Yij;
Mij(Aij==0) = M;                           % if Yij-Sij == 0 Mij = M;
out_im(Aij>=0) = ((B + Mij(Aij>=0)).*im(Aij>=0))./(Mij(Aij>=0)+im(Aij>=0));
out_im(Aij<0) = (Mij(Aij<0).*im(Aij<0))./ (Mij(Aij<0)+B-im(Aij<0));
```

I am not able to figure out where I'm going wrong.

A detailed explanation of what I'm trying to implement is given in the following paper:
Vonikakis, Vassilios, and Ioannis Andreadis. "Multi-scale image contrast enhancement." In Control, Automation, Robotics and Vision, 2008. ICARCV 2008. 10th International Conference on, pp. 856-861. IEEE, 2008.

Comment: have you profiled your code to see what lines are the most time consuming? "Run and time"

Comment: Care to summarize what this is doing for those of us who don't instantly know what "a simple pixel level center-surround image enhancement" is? Also, what is `M`?

Comment: I have edited the question based on your suggestions.

Comment: You are calling CE 4 *million* times?

Comment: minimal working example please...

Comment: CE is called once but for each iteration I'm calling the sub-function A(x,m).

Comment: Thanks @AnderBiguri for pointing out the number of calls to the sub-function. I have changed my code accordingly. Still there is a need for improvement. Can you suggest any other improvements.

Comment: I see you're sliding a window, but as the window moves, the newly computed values of `out(i,j)` are used for the computation of  the `out` values of the subsequent iteration, i.e., of `out(i, j+1)`, since `temp` is assigned within the loop. Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: @DanielG makes a very good point.  From intuition on how this is supposed to work, I think you've coded it incorrectly, and your input variable should be named differently from your output variable, so that the sliding window applies to the unmodified input variable.

Comment: Assuming the previous comment is true, factor out the sliding window into a convolution.  The rest can be done vectorized on the entire images: input, convolved/averaged, and output.

Comment: Thanks @DanielG for pointing out the logical error. Have update my code.

Comment: @Peter I have tried your way to do convolution and then vectorize, but I'm not able to get the desired result.

Comment: You have another typo in your reference code:  `Aij(1) = M/Yij-Sij;`  You're missing parentheses for the denominator

Comment: @Peter Have edited the code. Thanks.

Comment: @Peter The method that u suggested works correctly. There was no problem in the implementation either. The problem was that I was not changing the range of the image to 1-255 while giving the input. After changing the range it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to see if I could get those times down by processing with `colfilt`and `nlfilter`, since both are usually much faster than for-loops for sliding window image processing.
Both worked fine for relatively small windows. For an image of 2048x2048 pixels and a window of 10x10, the solution with `colfilt` takes about 5 seconds (on my personal computer). With a window of 21x21 the time jumped to 27 seconds, but that is still a relative improvement on the times displayed on the question. Unfortunately I don't have enough memory to colfilt using windows of 100x100, but the solution with nlfilter works, though taking about 120 seconds.

*Here the code*

**Solution with colfilt:**

```
function outval = enhancematrix(inputmatrix,M,B)
%Inputmatrix is a 2D matrix or column vector, outval is a 1D row vector.

% If inputmatrix is made of integers...
inputmatrix = double(inputmatrix);

%1. Compute S and Y
normFactor = 1 / (size(inputmatrix,1) + 1).^2; %Size of column.
S = normFactor*sum(inputmatrix,1); % Sum over the columns. 
Y = inputmatrix(ceil(size(inputmatrix,1)/2),:); % Center row.
% So far we have all S and Y, one value per column.

%2. Compute A(abs(Y-S)) 
A = Afunc(abs(S-Y),M);
% And all A: one value per column.

%3. The tricky part. If Y(i)-S(i) > 0 do something.
doPositive = (Y > S);
doNegative = ~doPositive;

outval = zeros(1,size(inputmatrix,2));

outval(doPositive) = (B + A(doPositive) .* Y(doPositive)) ./ (A(doPositive) + Y(doPositive));
outval(doNegative) = (A(doNegative) .* Y(doNegative)) ./ (A(doNegative) + B - Y(doNegative));

end

function out = Afunc(x,M)
% Input x is a row vector. Output is another row vector.
    out = x;
    out(x == 0) =  M;
    out(x ~= 0) = M./x(x ~= 0);
end
```

> And to call it, simply do:

```
M = 1000; B = 255; enhancenow = @(x) enhancematrix(x,M,B);
w = 21 % windowsize
result = colfilt(inputImage,[w w],'sliding',enhancenow);
```

**Solution with nlfilter:**

```
function outval = enhanceimagecontrast(neighbourhood,M,B)

%1. Compute S and Y
normFactor = 1 / (length(neighbourhood) + 1).^2;
S = normFactor*sum(neighbourhood(:));
Y = neighbourhood(ceil(size(neighbourhood,1)/2),ceil(size(neighbourhood,2)/2));


%2. Compute A(abs(Y-S))
test = (Y>=S);
A = Afunc(abs(Y-S),M);

%3. Return outval
if test
    outval = ((B + A) * Y) / (A + Y);
else
    outval = (A * Y) / (A + B - Y);
end


function aval = Afunc(x,M)
if (x == 0)
    aval = M;
else
    aval = M/x;
end
```

> And to call it, simply do:

```
M = 1000; B = 255; enhancenow = @(x) enhanceimagecontrast(x,M,B);
w = 21 % windowsize
result = nlfilter(inputImage,[w w], enhancenow);
```

I didn't spend much time checking that everything is 100% correct, but I did see some nice contrast enhancement (hair looks particularly nice).

Comment: colfilt did not work in my PC either for 100*100 window size. I tried  nlfilter and found two things. One is that normFactor should be `normFactor = 1 / (length(neighbourhood) + 1).^2;` and that Y is not the center of the neighborhood when we use `Y = neighbourhood(ceil(length(neighbourhood)/2));`. So I changed it to `Y = neighbourhood(ceil(size(neighbourhood,1)/2),ceil(size(neighbourhood,2)/2));`. And also care should be taken to make the input images in the range 1 - 255 as we have selected `B = 255;`. And thanks for introducing me to new style of coding. Its interesting what you have done.

Comment: Thanks, just updated the code. Colfilt is usually very fast, but because it allocates all windows as columns in a temporary matrix, it ends up requesting too much memory if the window size is too large. One can actually call it like `result = colfilt(inputImage,[w w],[w2 w2], 'sliding',enhancenow);`. The second window `w2` tells Matlab to split the processing in blocks, to save memory (see [documentation](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/colfilt.html) ).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is the implementation that was suggested by [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1401351/peter). I debugged the implementation and presenting the final working version of the fast implementation.

```
function [out_im] = CE_conv(im,s,M)
B = 255;
im = ( im - min(im(:)) ) ./ ( max(im(:)) - min(im(:)) )*255;
h = ones(s,s)./(s*s);
out1 = imfilter(im,h,'conv');
out_im = im;
Aij = im-out1;                             %same as Yij-Sij
Aij1 = out1-im;                            %same as Sij-Yij
Mij = Aij;
Mij(Aij>0) = M./Aij(Aij>0);                % if Yij>Sij  Mij = M/(Yij-Sij);
Mij(Aij<0) = M./Aij1(Aij<0);               % if Yij<Sij  Mij = M/(Sij-Yij);
Mij(Aij==0) = M;                           % if Yij-Sij == 0 Mij = M;
out_im(Aij>=0) = ((B + Mij(Aij>=0)).*im(Aij>=0))./(Mij(Aij>=0)+im(Aij>=0));
out_im(Aij<0) = (Mij(Aij<0).*im(Aij<0))./ (Mij(Aij<0)+B-im(Aij<0));
out_im = ( out_im - min(out_im(:)) ) ./ ( max(out_im(:)) - min(out_im(:)) );
```

> To call this use the following code

```
I = imread('pout.tif');
w_size = 51;
M = 4000;
output = CE_conv(I(:,:,1),w_size,M);
```

> The output for the 'pout.tif' image is given below

[image]

The execution time for Bigger image and with 100*100 block size is around 5 secs with this implementation.